# Unable to autoload constant in rails development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

whenever i hit the api in development mode it throws the below error. attached the path of the controller.

When i removed the model class, i don't get any error, but when i added the contractor model i am getting errors.

Also whenever i changed the association to embeds many and changed the routes to plural(resources) it's working fine. but actually my use case needs singular route and embeds_one association between two models.

Kindly help me in solving this issue, i can't able to figure out the reasons.

routes:

```
api_term_loan_contractor GET /term_loans/:term_loan_id/contractor(.:format) api/v1/term_loans/contractors#show {:format=>:json}

 PATCH  /term_loans/:term_loan_id/contractor(.:format)   api/v1/term_loans/contractors#update {:format=>:json}

 PUT    /term_loans/:term_loan_id/contractor(.:format)  api/v1/term_loans/contractors#update {:format=>:json}
```

Controller:

Path: /RubymineProjects/ca-loans-api/app/controllers/api/v1/term_loans/contractors_controller.rb

```
module Api
  module V1
    module TermLoans
      class ContractorsController < ApplicationController
        def show
          render json: {'hi': 'hi', 'name': 'giri'}
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Model: /RubymineProjects/ca-loans-api/app/models/term_loan/contractor.rb

```
module TermLoan
  class Contractor
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    field :name, type: String

    embedded_in :transaction, class_name: 'TermLoan::Transaction'
  end
end
```

TermLoan Model: RubymineProjects/ca-loans-api/app/models/term_loan/transaction.rb

```
module TermLoan
  class Transaction < ::Transaction
    embeds_one :contractor, class_name: 'TermLoan::Contractor', cascade_callbacks: true
  end
end
```

Exception

```
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Contractor, expected RubymineProjects/ca-loans-api/app/models/term_loan/contractor.rb to define it):
  
activesupport (5.2.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:511:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (5.2.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:195:in `const_missing'
activesupport (5.2.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:542:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (5.2.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:195:in `const_missing'
activesupport (5.2.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:542:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (5.2.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:195:in `const_missing'
activesupport (5.2.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:542:in `load_missing_constant'
```

Comment: Is this description `Model: /RubymineProjects/ca-loans-api/app/controllers/api/v1/term_loans/contractors_controller.rb` right? Does all classes follow the rails way? (path app/models/term_loan/transaction.rb mus contains class TermLoan::Transaction)

Comment: @SergioBelevskij edited my question, that was a typo.